# how to do pattern matching using regular expression of perl in consecutive lines?

Tags: regex, perl, verilog

I want to do a pattern matching of `.Q(`.
There can be unlimited space between `.Q` and `(`.
It can even go to the next line.
For a particular case, I have the statement as :

```
dff dff_reg_1(.CP

       (clk), .D (data), .Q

       (output))
```

I tried to use `($statement =~ /.Q(\s*)\(/)` but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any other way to capture this?

(PS: apologies for so many edits, the backslash is not appearing properly)

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't seem to work.`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot and there is no need to double escape the `(` symbol.

```
($statement =~ /\.Q(\s*)\(/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$statement =~/\.Q\s*\(/
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot to all of you

```
$statement =~ /.Q\s*\(/x
```

This pattern search fixed my problem.

I also got to know of an [amazing site for debugging perl script](http://regex101.com/)